# Flexslider appear to be perfect in Chrome but in IE and Firefox it cuts off

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexslider

I have a flexslider images on my page(s), and I can't seem to figure out why the images are displaying in a different location in IE vs. Chrome. Does anyone have any advice how I can make the location consistent regardless of browser? Chrome is showing in the correct location, and IE has the images pushed over to the top off the boundary of my page

How it display in chrome Windows 8

[image]

How it Display in IE Windows 8

[image]

Im using  jQuery FlexSlider v2.2.0

Please help me im been struggling with this code for two days and I dont know what the problem is

Flexslider CSS

```css
.flex-container a:active,
.flexslider a:active,
.flex-container a:focus,
.flexslider a:focus  {outline: none;}
.slides,
.flex-control-nav,
.flex-direction-nav {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}

/* FlexSlider Necessary Styles
*********************************/
.flexslider {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.flexslider .slides > li {display: none; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;} /* Hide the slides before the JS is loaded. Avoids image jumping */
.flexslider .slides img {width: 100%; display: block;}
.flex-control-thumbs img {cursor:pointer;}
.flex-pauseplay span {text-transform: capitalize;}

/* Clearfix for the .slides element */
.slides:after {content: "\0020"; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; line-height: 0; height: 0;}
html[xmlns] .slides {display: block;}
* html .slides {height: 100%;}

/* No JavaScript Fallback */
/* If you are not using another script, such as Modernizr, make sure you
 * include js that eliminates this class on page load */
.no-js .slides > li:first-child {display: block;}

/* FlexSlider Default Theme
*********************************/
.flexslider {overflow:hidden; position: relative; z-index:2;}
.flexslider.top_slider {min-height:564px; background-color:#ccc;}
.flexslider.top_slider:before {
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 z-index:3;
 left:0;
 bottom:0;
 width:100%;
 height:80px;
 background-image:url(../images/slider/slide_shadow.png);
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 background-size:auto 100%;
 -webkit-background-size:auto 100%;
}
.flex-viewport { max-height: 2000px; -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; -moz-transition: all 1s ease; -o-transition: all 1s ease; transition: all 1s ease; }
.loading .flex-viewport { max-height: 300px; }
.flexslider .slides { zoom: 1; }
.carousel li { margin-right: 5px; }



/* Direction Nav */
.flexslider.top_slider .flex-direction-nav {
 position:relative;
 margin:0 auto;
}

.flexslider.top_slider .flex-direction-nav li a {
 position:absolute;
 z-index:300;
 bottom:50px;
 display:block;
 width:70px;
 height:70px;
 font-family:FontAwesome;
 text-align:center;
 background-color:#fff;
}
.flexslider.top_slider .flex-direction-nav li a:hover {background-color:#333;}
.flexslider.top_slider .flex-direction-nav li a.flex-prev {left:0;}
.flexslider.top_slider .flex-direction-nav li a.flex-next {left:71px;}
.flexslider.top_slider .flex-direction-nav li a:before {
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 width:70px;
 height:70px;
 line-height:66px;
 font-size:32px;
 color:#333;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; 
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.flexslider.top_slider .flex-direction-nav li a.flex-prev:before {content: "\f104";}
.flexslider.top_slider .flex-direction-nav li a.flex-next:before {content: "\f105";}
.flexslider.top_slider .flex-direction-nav li a:hover:before {color:#fff;}



/* __________ Portfolio Post Direction Nav __________ */
.flexslider.portfolio_single_slider {position:relative;}
.flexslider.portfolio_single_slider .flex-direction-nav li a {
 position:absolute;
 z-index:300;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 display:block;
 width:200px;
 height:100%;
 font-family:FontAwesome;
 text-align:center;
 opacity:0;
}
.flexslider.portfolio_single_slider .flex-direction-nav li a:hover {background:none;}
.flexslider.portfolio_single_slider .flex-direction-nav li a.flex-prev {left:-50px;}
.flexslider.portfolio_single_slider .flex-direction-nav li a.flex-next {right:-50px;}
.flexslider.portfolio_single_slider:hover .flex-direction-nav li a.flex-prev {left:0; opacity:1;}
.flexslider.portfolio_single_slider:hover .flex-direction-nav li a.flex-next {right:0; opacity:1;}
.flexslider.portfolio_single_slider .flex-direction-nav li a:before {
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 width:70px;
 height:70px;
 margin-top:-35px;
 line-height:66px;
 font-size:32px;
 color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; 
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.flexslider.portfolio_single_slider .flex-direction-nav li a.flex-prev:before {content: "\f104"; left:0;}
.flexslider.portfolio_single_slider .flex-direction-nav li a.flex-next:before {content: "\f105"; right:0;}
.flexslider.portfolio_single_slider .flex-direction-nav li a:hover:before {color:#fff;}



/* __________ Control Navigation __________ */
.flex-control-nav {
 position:absolute;
 z-index:300;
 left:0;
 bottom:30px;
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
}
.flex-control-nav li {
 display:inline-block;
 margin:0 8px;
}
.flex-control-nav li a {
 display:block;
 width:10px;
 height:10px;
 border-radius:50%;
 border:2px solid #333;
 background-color:#fff;
 font-size:0;
 cursor:pointer;
 transition: none;
 -webkit-transition: none;
}
.flex-control-nav li a.flex-active {
 position:relative;
 top:-3px;
 left:-3px;
 right:-3px;
 width:16px;
 height:16px;
 background-color:#333;
 cursor:default;
}




/* Pause/Play */
.flex-pauseplay a { display: block; width: 20px; height: 20px; position: absolute; bottom: 5px; left: 10px; opacity: 0.8; z-index: 10; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer; color: #000; }
.flex-pauseplay a:before  { font-family: "flexslider-icon"; font-size: 20px; display: inline-block; content: '\f004'; }
.flex-pauseplay a:hover  { opacity: 1; }
.flex-pauseplay a.flex-play:before { content: '\f003'; }



/* Works Slider */
.flexslider.works_slider .flex-direction-nav li a {
 position:absolute;
 z-index:300;
 bottom:30px;
 display:block;
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 font-family:FontAwesome;
 text-align:center;
 background-color:#fff;
}
.flexslider.works_slider .flex-direction-nav li a:hover {background-color:#333;}
.flexslider.works_slider .flex-direction-nav li a.flex-prev {left:20px;}
.flexslider.works_slider .flex-direction-nav li a.flex-next {left:70px;}
.flexslider.works_slider .flex-direction-nav li a:before {
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 line-height:46px;
 font-size:32px;
 color:#333;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; 
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.flexslider.works_slider .flex-direction-nav li a.flex-prev:before {content: "\f104";}
.flexslider.works_slider .flex-direction-nav li a.flex-next:before {content: "\f105";}
.flexslider.works_slider .flex-direction-nav li a:hover:before {color:#fff;}




/* Control Nav */
.flex-control-thumbs {
 position: absolute;
 z-index:200;
 left:0;
 bottom:50px;
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
}
.flex-control-thumbs li {
 overflow:hidden;
 position:relative;
 display:inline-block;
 width: 100px;
 height:70px;
 margin: 0 5px;
}
.flex-control-thumbs img {
 position:asbolute;
 width: auto;
 max-width:none;
 height:100%;
 display: block;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.flex-control-thumbs li img.flex-active:before {
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
 border:5px solid #fff;
}


/* thumb navigation */
#carousel {
 position:absolute;
 left:1px;
 bottom:45px;
 width:100%;
}
#carousel .slides {text-align:center;}
#carousel .slides li {
 overflow:hidden;
 z-index:10 !important;
 float:none !important;
 display:inline-block !important;
 padding:5px 0 0;
 width:105px !important;
 height:75px !important;
 margin:0 2px 0 5px !important;
 opacity:1 !important;
 cursor:pointer;
 box-shadow:3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}
#carousel .slides li.flex-active-slide:before {
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 top:5px;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
 border:5px solid transparent;
}
#carousel .slides li.flex-active-slide:before {border-color:#fff;}

#carousel .slides li.flex-active-slide:after {
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 left:50%;
 top:0;
 margin-left:-2px;
 width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
}

#carousel .slides li img {
 width:auto;
 max-width:none;
 height:100%;
}





/* Caption */
.top_slider .slide1 {
 height:100%;
 background-image:url(../images/slider/slide1_bg.jpg);
 background-size:cover;
 background-attachment:fixed !important;
}

.top_slider .slide1 .flex_caption1 {
 position:absolute;
 z-index:30;
 left:50%;
 top:45%;
 width:100%;
 margin-left:-585px;
 color:#fff;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.top_slider .slide1 .flex_caption1 .title1 {margin-bottom:15px; display:inline-block; font-weight:500; line-height:80px; font-size:80px;}
.top_slider .slide1 .flex_caption1 .title2 {margin-bottom:15px; display:inline-block; font-weight:100; line-height:80px; font-size:80px;}
.top_slider .slide1 .flex_caption1 .title3 {margin-bottom:15px; display:inline-block; font-weight:100; line-height:80px; font-size:80px;}
.top_slider .slide1 .flex_caption1 .title4 {margin-bottom:15px; width:680px; font-weight:300; line-height:34px; font-size:26px;}



.top_slider .slide2 {
 height:100%;
 background-image:url(../images/slider/slide2_bg.jpg);
 background-size:cover;
 background-attachment:fixed !important;
}

.top_slider .slide2 .flex_caption1 {
 position:absolute;
 z-index:30;
 left:50%;
 top:45%;
 width:100%;
 margin-left:-585px;
 color:#fff;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.top_slider .slide2 .flex_caption1 .title1 {margin-bottom:15px; display:inline-block; font-weight:500; line-height:80px; font-size:80px;}
.top_slider .slide2 .flex_caption1 .title2 {margin-bottom:15px; display:inline-block; font-weight:100; line-height:80px; font-size:80px;}
.top_slider .slide2 .flex_caption1 .title3 {margin-bottom:15px; display:inline-block; font-weight:100; line-height:80px; font-size:80px;}
.top_slider .slide2 .flex_caption1 .title4 {margin-bottom:15px; width:680px; font-weight:300; line-height:34px; font-size:26px;}


.top_slider .slide3 {
 height:100%;
 background-image:url(../images/slider/slide3_bg.jpg);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
}

.top_slider .slide3 .flex_caption1 {
 position:absolute;
 z-index:30;
 left:50%;
 top:45%;
 width:100%;
 margin-left:-585px;
 color:#fff;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.top_slider .slide3 .flex_caption1 .title1 {margin-bottom:15px; display:inline-block; font-weight:500; line-height:80px; font-size:80px;}
.top_slider .slide3 .flex_caption1 .title2 {margin-bottom:15px; display:inline-block; font-weight:100; line-height:80px; font-size:80px;}
.top_slider .slide3 .flex_caption1 .title3 {margin-bottom:15px; display:inline-block; font-weight:100; line-height:80px; font-size:80px;}
.top_slider .slide3 .flex_caption1 .title4 {margin-bottom:15px; width:680px; font-weight:300; line-height:34px; font-size:26px;}


.top_slider .slide_btn {
 position:absolute;
 z-index:110;
 bottom:50px;
 left:50%;
 width:171px;
 display:inline-block;
 margin-left:414px;
 padding:26px 30px 24px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-weight:900;
 color:#333;
 background-color:#fff;
}
.top_slider .slide_btn:hover {background-color:#1c1c1c; color:#fff;}
.top_slider .slide_btn:before {
 position:absolute;
 content: "\f105";
 right:30px;
 top:0;
 width:20px;
 height:20px;
 font-family:FontAwesome;
 text-align:right;
 line-height:66px;
 font-size:32px;
 color:#333;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; 
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.top_slider .slide_btn:hover:before {color:#fff;}




/* __________ Video Slide __________ */
.slide3 .buttonBar {display:none;}

#controlBar_P2 {display:none !important;}

.slide3.bg {
 height:100%;
 background-image:url(../images/slider/slide3_bg.jpg);
 background-size:cover;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#carousel .slides li .video {
 position:absolute;
 left:50%;
 top:50%;
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
 margin:-15px 0 0 -15px;
 background-image:url(../images/video.png);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:100% auto;
 -webkit-background-size:100% auto;
}

/* _________ //Video Slide _________ */









/* Flex Caption Effect */
.FadeIn, .FromTop, .FromRight, .FromBottom, .FromLeft {opacity: 0; transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out; -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;}
.captionDelay1 {transition-delay: 0.1s; -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;}
.captionDelay2 {transition-delay: 0.2s; -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;}
.captionDelay3 {transition-delay: 0.3s; -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;}
.captionDelay4 {transition-delay: 0.4s; -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;}
.captionDelay5 {transition-delay: 0.5s; -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;}
.captionDelay6 {transition-delay: 0.6s; -webkit-transition-delay: 0.6s;}
.captionDelay7 {transition-delay: 0.7s; -webkit-transition-delay: 0.7s;}
.captionDelay8 {transition-delay: 0.8s; -webkit-transition-delay: 0.8s;}
.captionDelay9 {transition-delay: 0.9s; -webkit-transition-delay: 0.9s;}
.captionDelay10 {transition-delay: 1s; -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;}
.captionDelay11{transition-delay: 1.1s; -webkit-transition-delay: 1.1s;}
.captionDelay12 {transition-delay: 1.2s; -webkit-transition-delay: 1.2s;}

.flexslider li.flex-active-slide .FadeIn {opacity: 1;}
.flexslider li .FromTop {transform: translateY(-100%); -o-transform: translateY(-100%); -ms-transform: translateY(-100%); -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);}
.flexslider li.flex-active-slide .FromTop {opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0); -o-transform: translateY(0%); -ms-transform: translateY(0); -webkit-transform: translateY(0);}
.flexslider li .FromBottom {transform: translateY(100%); -o-transform: translateY(100%); -ms-transform: translateY(100%); -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);}
.flexslider li.flex-active-slide .FromBottom {opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0); -o-transform: translateY(0); -ms-transform: translateY(0); -webkit-transform: translateY(0);}
.flexslider li .FromLeft {transform: translateX(-100%); -o-transform: translateX(-100%); -ms-transform: translateX(-100%); -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);}
.flexslider li.flex-active-slide .FromLeft {opacity: 1; transform: translateX(0); -o-transform: translateX(0); -ms-transform: translateX(0); -webkit-transform: translateX(0);}
.flexslider li .FromRight {transform: translateX(100%); -o-transform: translateX(100%); -ms-transform: translateX(100%); -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);}
.flexslider li.flex-active-slide .FromRight {opacity: 1; transform: translateX(0); -o-transform: translateX(0); -ms-transform: translateX(0); -webkit-transform: translateX(0);}








/* Responsive Styles */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
 .top_slider .slide1 .flex_caption1, .top_slider .slide2 .flex_caption1, .top_slider .slide3 .flex_caption1 {margin-left:-485px;}
 .top_slider .slide1 .flex_caption1 .title1, .top_slider .slide1 .flex_caption1 .title2, .top_slider .slide1 .flex_caption1 .title3, .top_slider .slide2 .flex_caption1 .title1, .top_slider .slide2 .flex_caption1 .title2, .top_slider .slide2 .flex_caption1 .title3, .top_slider .slide3 .flex_caption1 .title1, .top_slider .slide3 .flex_caption1 .title2, .top_slider .slide3 .flex_caption1 .title3 {font-size:70px; line-height:70px;}
 .top_slider .slide_btn {margin-left:314px;}
 
 
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
 .top_slider .slide1 .flex_caption1, .top_slider .slide2 .flex_caption1, .top_slider .slide3 .flex_caption1 {margin-left:-375px;}
 .top_slider .slide1 .flex_caption1 .title1, .top_slider .slide1 .flex_caption1 .title2, .top_slider .slide1 .flex_caption1 .title3, .top_slider .slide2 .flex_caption1 .title1, .top_slider .slide2 .flex_caption1 .title2, .top_slider .slide2 .flex_caption1 .title3, .top_slider .slide3 .flex_caption1 .title1, .top_slider .slide3 .flex_caption1 .title2, .top_slider .slide3 .flex_caption1 .title3 {font-size:60px; line-height:60px;}
 .top_slider .slide_btn {margin-left:204px;}
 
 .top_slider .slide1 .flex_caption1 .title4, .top_slider .slide2 .flex_caption1 .title4, .top_slider .slide3 .flex_caption1 .title4 {font-size:17px; line-height:24px; width:450px;}
 
 
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
 .flexslider.top_slider:before {height:40px;}
 
 
 .top_slider .slide1 .flex_caption1, .top_slider .slide2 .flex_caption1, .top_slider .slide3 .flex_caption1 {margin-left:0; left:15px;}
 .top_slider .slide1 .flex_caption1 .title1, .top_slider .slide1 .flex_caption1 .title2, .top_slider .slide1 .flex_caption1 .title3, .top_slider .slide2 .flex_caption1 .title1, .top_slider .slide2 .flex_caption1 .title2, .top_slider .slide2 .flex_caption1 .title3, .top_slider .slide3 .flex_caption1 .title1, .top_slider .slide3 .flex_caption1 .title2, .top_slider .slide3 .flex_caption1 .title3 {font-size:40px; line-height:40px;}
 
 .top_slider .slide1 .flex_caption1 .title4, .top_slider .slide2 .flex_caption1 .title4, .top_slider .slide3 .flex_caption1 .title4 {font-size:13px; line-height:19px; width:420px;}
 
 
 #carousel .slides li {width:70px !important; height:55px !important; margin:0 0 0 2px !important;}
 
 
 .flexslider.top_slider .flex-direction-nav li a {width:50px; height:50px;}
 .flexslider.top_slider .flex-direction-nav li a.flex-next {left:51px;}
 .flexslider.top_slider .flex-direction-nav li a:before {width:50px; height:50px; line-height:46px;}
 
 
 .top_slider .slide_btn {padding:15px 20px 15px 5px; width:auto; left:auto; right:15px; margin:0;}
 .top_slider .slide_btn:before {right:5px; font-size:18px; top:-7px;}
 
 
}

@media (max-width: 479px) {
 .top_slider .slide1 .flex_caption1 .title1, .top_slider .slide1 .flex_caption1 .title2, .top_slider .slide1 .flex_caption1 .title3, .top_slider .slide2 .flex_caption1 .title1, .top_slider .slide2 .flex_caption1 .title2, .top_slider .slide2 .flex_caption1 .title3, .top_slider .slide3 .flex_caption1 .title1, .top_slider .slide3 .flex_caption1 .title2, .top_slider .slide3 .flex_caption1 .title3 {font-size:26px; line-height:26px;}
 
 .top_slider .slide1 .flex_caption1 .title4, .top_slider .slide2 .flex_caption1 .title4, .top_slider .slide3 .flex_caption1 .title4 {width:290px;}
 
 #carousel {display:none;}
 
 
}
```

Comment: can you reproduce the problem in a jsfiddle?

Comment: How do I use Jsfiddle

Comment: Can you hlp me plz i need to host this website tonight